# How to vocalize and control very low/growl notes

Tags: bass-voice

I've recently become obsessed with acapella groups (pentatonix, voiceplay, home free), mainly their bass singers. I really want to sing notes in the first octave like they do. I can make a kind of croaking or a growling sound and hit the notes but I cant hit the exact pitches or form words. I just end up hitting the note and the 3 notes around it. I just want to hit the note and form words or make it sound smoother. Most of my searching isnt helpful because everything I go to is either telling me how to growl or how to find my vocal range.

Answer (score 1):

I found this series of videos by David Larson who is both impressive and very clear in describing variations on subharmonic singing, vocal fry, and throat singing.

- his first, with some errors

- the second

- vocal fry vs. subharmonic bass.

Really astonishing to see this. Good luck!